# How do I use this Dictionary in a main.ml File (Create a dictionary , add elements, remove .... )?

Tags: dictionary, ocaml

I have found an impletantion of a dictionary and your implementation. I want to create a dictionary using those modules below, but I'm getting this error:

> Unbound Value.

I'm new to the functional paradigm. I tried this book, but I'm still lost: http://dev.realworldocaml.org/maps-and-hashtables.html

And 
Dictionary and AssociateList from here: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2014sp/recitations/7/functional-stacks-queues-dictionaries-fractions.html

```ml
let x = Dictionary.AssocList.create ;;

open Dictionary.AssocList
enviroment = create() 
Unbound type constructor stringAssocListAssocList

module type DICTIONARY =
  sig
    (* An 'a dict is a mapping from strings to 'a.                                                                                                                                
       We write {k1->v1, k2->v2, ...} for the dictionary which                                                                                                                    
       maps k1 to v1, k2 to v2, and so forth. *)
    type key = string
    type 'a dict

    (* make an empty dictionary carrying 'a values *)
    val make : unit -> 'a dict

    (* insert a key and value into the dictionary *)
    val insert : 'a dict -> key -> 'a -> 'a dict

    (* Return the value that a key maps to in the dictionary.                                                                                                                     
     * Raise NotFound if there is not mapping for the key. *)
    val lookup : 'a dict -> key -> 'a
    exception NotFound

    (* applies a function to all the elements of a dictionary;                                                                                                                    
       i.e., if a dictionary d maps a string s to an element a,                                                                                                                   
       then the dictionary (map f d) will map s to f(a). *)
    val map : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a dict -> 'b dict
  end

module AssocList : DICTIONARY =
  struct
    type key = string
    type 'a dict = (key * 'a) list

    (* AF: The list [(k1,v1), (k2,v2), ...] represents the dictionary                                                                                                             
     * {k1 -> v1, k2 -> v2, ...}, except that if a key occurs                                                                                                                     
     * multiple times in the list, only the earliest one matters.                                                                                                                 
     * RI: true.                                                                                                                                                                  
     *)

    let make() : 'a dict = []

    let insert (d : 'a dict) (k : key) (x : 'a) : 'a dict =
      (k, x) :: d

    exception NotFound

    let rec lookup (d : 'a dict) (k : key) : 'a =
      match d with
      | [] -> raise NotFound
      | (k', x) :: rest ->
         if k = k' then x
         else lookup rest k
    let map (f : 'a -> 'b) (d : 'a dict) =
      List.map (fun (k, a) -> (k, f a)) d
  end
```

Comment: I've edited your question in order to try to make more sense of it. Please look it over to make sure I got it right. (I've no idea what "impletantion" means...)

Comment: No wait, "Unbound type constructor stringAssocListAssocList" is an error message, right?

Comment: @NisseEngström I think there is a superfluous `stringAssocList` in there

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your dictionary implementation is saved in a file named `dictionary.ml`. To use this module, you would `open` it, and gives `AssocList` a shorter name for convenient (optional)

```ml
open Dictionary
module D = AssocList
```

To create a new, empty dictionary, you'll do:

```ml
let dict = D.make ()
```

To insert element, and make a new dict out of that, you'll do:

```ml
let new_dict = D.insert dict "one" 1
```

`"one"` is the key and `1` is the value.

If you want to see all elements in the dictionary, you'll have to make a new function, or make the `(key * 'a) list` type available, something like this in your signature

```ml
type 'a dict = (key * 'a) list (* This will make dict elements available *)
type 'a dict (* This will make the dict available but you can't view the elements *)
```